# How to connect with multiple DBs in a asp.net web application?

Tags: c#-2.0, database-connection, asp.net-2.0, connection-string

I have a application which validates UserID - UserID is of 32 digit UID......

i need to validate the UID to find where this user exists in

database 'A' or 'B' or 'c' or 'D'or 'E'or 'F'

reply me your ideas..

ps: 
databases may ex-tern at later ....

so i need a dynamic connection string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use the support from a framework like [spring.net](http://www.springframework.net/)

I've done this before with that framework. You could declare as many datasources as you need and decide in runtime wich one you should use. Also using this kind of frameworks improves the quality and perfomance of your application.